# How to change the focus when user validate the EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

in my case, the user have to give hours and mins, but I can't find how to give the focus to the mins whey I enter the hours with one caracter. The hours can be one or two caracters so I want to do this even if I give only one caracter and validate with the keyboard. 
There is my code :

```
ed_nbHeure.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(ed_nbHeure.length()>1){
                    ed_nbMin.requestFocus();
                }


            }
        });
```

I want to know how to call the action of validation with the keyboard to change the focus.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I just had to use the .setOnEditorActionListener() like this :

```
ed_nbHeure.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    ed_nbMin.requestFocus();

                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ed_nbHeure.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length()==1){
                    ed_nbMin.requestFocus();
                }


            }
        });
```

Add this condition in `afterTextChanged`

```
if(s.length()==1)
{
     ed_nbMin.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: If I do this i can't enter two caracters

Comment: @NeoKerd just change condition for enter character length

Comment: I want to know how to call the action of validation with the keyboard to change the focus